# ClientDataSet filter with "NOT LIKE"

Tags: delphi, filter, tclientdataset

When using the Filter property of the ClientDataSet with filter

> Name NOT LIKE 'Paulo%'

says that the syntax is incorrect.

how can I make a workaround in the filter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the Filter syntax to

```
  Clientdataset.Filter := 'NOT [Name]  LIKE ' +QuotedStr('Paulo%');
```

Comment: the Filter property always needs "(parentheses)"

the filter worked with '(NOT (Name LIKE'%P')) '

thanks for the reply.

Comment: with wich version do you need parentheses. I tested with D7, DXE, DXE3 and : `begin
  With Clientdataset1 do
    begin
     FieldDefs.Add('Name',ftString,100);
     Createdataset;
     Append;
     Fields[0].Value:='Test';
     Append;
     Fields[0].Value:='Paulox';
     Append;
     Fields[0].Value:='Pauloy';
     Post;
     Filter := 'NOT [Name]  LIKE ' +QuotedStr('Paulo%');
     Filtered := true;
    end;
end;`

Comment: ok, my mistake was put equal to SQL, denying the LIKE command " WHERE Name NOT LIKE 'Paulo%' ", but in SQL the two ways is acceptable " WHERE NOT Name LIKE 'Paulo%' ".
Thanks, your answer is right.